# Find elements by id /xpath that contains dots/ dash

Tags: .net, selenium-webdriver

Unable to locate elements on Firefox web driver (selenium) by XPath / ID / tagName ...
all these tags contains dash "-" , dot "." in their names.

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-10 col-md-9 col-lg-8 form-field">
    <div class="sn-stream-textarea-container">
        <span class="sn-stream-input-decorator" style="background-color: gold"></span>
        <textarea id="activity-stream-work_notes-textarea" aria-label="Work notes (fulfiller only)" class="sn-string-textarea form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-empty ng-valid-required"
            placeholder="Work notes (fulfiller only)" data-stream-text-input="work_notes" ng-required="activity_field_1.mandatory &amp;&amp; !activity_field_1.filled" ng-model="activity_field_1.value" ng-attr-placeholder="{{activity_field_1.label}}" sn-sync-with="activity_field_1.name"
            sn-sync-with-value-in-fn="reduceMentions(text)" sn-sync-with-value-out-fn="expandMentions(text)" mentio="" mentio-id="'activity-stream-work_notes-textarea'" mentio-typed-term="typedTerm" mentio-require-leading-space="true" mentio-trigger-char="'@'"
            mentio-items="members" mentio-search="searchMembersAsync(term)" mentio-template-url="/at-mentions.tpl" mentio-select="selectAtMention(item)" mentio-suppress-trailing-space="true" sn-resize-height="" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; height: 64px;"
            autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false">
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <ul id="fieldmsg-singleinput-7" class="ng-hide" tabindex="-1" ng-show="activity_field_1.messages.length > 0" aria-hidden="true">
        <!-- ngRepeat: msg in activity_field_1.messages -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Code attempts

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//[@id='activity-stream-work_notes-textarea']")).SendKeys("Test");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("activity-stream-work_notes-textarea")).SendKeys("test");
```

Getting an error:

> Unable to locate element: #activity\-stream\-work_notes\textarea

somehow it adds "\" before the dash / dot although its accepting the underscore "_".

[See screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ2cG.png)

Comment: Please, attach html of element you r looking for.

Comment: @IPolnik attached the html tags

Comment: My guess is that the `\\`s are being added to the error message incorrectly but are not actually being inserted as part of the locator. Does the XPath you have listed throw the same exact error? Have you looked to see if the element you are looking for is in an IFRAME? Have you added a wait to make sure the element is visible before attempting to locate it?

Comment: it was hiding under 2 iframes thanks Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath,

```
driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//textarea[contains(@aria-label,'Work notes')]")).SendKeys("test");
```

Comment: yet unable to locate the element , very strange cause the id exists and it should be very easy to grap , don't need xpath or cssselector , id should be fine

Comment: The id property did not work.that why i tried with xpath which worked perfectly. There is a chance that these elements are hiding behind iframes. please check for existence of iframes in the html source.

Comment: Its could be, but usually if your element hiding behind other element u will get different error message - "Other element would receive the click: .." which is means elements is found, but driver can't click on it, but in his case element is not found on page....

Comment: thanks guys it worked the element was hiding under 2 iframes

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to use IDs when they are available. This will work:

driver.FindElement(By.cssSelector("textarea[id='activity-stream-work_notes-textarea']")).SendKeys("test");

Comment: hi David , it didn't work same error unable to locate the element

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath - driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//div/div/textarea"));

Comment: driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div/div[@id='activity-stream-work_notes-textarea']")).SendKeys("Offboarding has been completed successfully.");

Comment: Can u share your code then, probably your problem is not with element, I never had an issue with Xpath even with IE.

Answer (score 0):

the element was hiding under 2 iframes , now im able to locate it after switching to the correct iframe 
thank you guys for your help !